# Weblogic 12 with java7 doesnt set nill in JAXBElement

Tags: java, jaxb, weblogic

We have application running on weblogic 11g using java 6. Now we want to use use weblogic 12c with java 7 but we have some problem. We are using JAXB to un/marshal soap request. Now when we deploy our application to wls12 we have problem with nillable atribut in element. When I send xml with:

```
<data:MyElement state="ok" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

element in my app isnt nill:

```
element.isNil() return false
```

JUnit with this test still works so I supposed that there is no problem with java7. This problem occurs just on wls12. How should I fix this problem or at least how should I debug it

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To future generation which will have this problem too:

When I turn on tracing messages, this problem occurs again.

```
org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=TRACE
```

By debugging I saw that wls 12 use `oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.soap11.Message11`and wls 10 use `weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl`

All I need to do is to add this class to messageFactory:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Difference Between WebLogic 11 & 12

Starting in WebLogic 12.1.1 [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) is the default [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html

### What is Causing the Failure

You are hitting the following MOXy bug.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/404926

### What You Can Do:

1. If you are an Oracle Support customer then you can contact them to get an official fix.
2. You can revert to using the JAXB RI at the server or application level using the offical instructions that can be found here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/data_types.htm#CIHBHDGI

Comment: thx for the help. Is there a way how to test it if I did it right ? I am not sure  because in wls home I didnt find weblogic.jar just weblogic-classes.jar which doesnt contains files mention in META-INF

Comment: I try all solution in oracle documentation but with no success.

Comment: @hudi - Even the `modules/databinding.override_1.0.0.0.jar` option?

Comment: yes this was the first options which I tried. Just add this library to my weblogic classpath and restart it. But nillable still doesnt work and I dont know how to test which provider/binding is used

Comment: @hudi - Deploy a servlet that creates a new `JAXBContext`, then output the result of calling `getClass()` on it.  If the package starts with `org.eclipse.persistence` it is still EclipseLink as the provider.  If it starts with `com.sun` then it is the JAXB RI.

Comment: hm thx I have still eclipse: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext

Comment: @hudi - Are you using WebLogic 12.1.1 or 12.1.2?

Comment: I have weblogic 12.1.2

Comment: @hudi - Do you have the `xmlns:xsi` namespace declaration in your XML document?

Comment: my bad your solution works like a charm. I have two application. All of them using jaxbContext but I modify just second one.

Comment: just to add this mean just second solution in oracle documentation works. Because I try first and third too which should change jaxbContext to all application in my server